# Chrome extension with content script on extension icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to put something to work but I am totally confused about googles "isolated worlds". I searched a lot but I cannot find the answer to my needs.
Workflow: User clicks on extension icon -> a javascript will search on DOM tree for a div "xpto and get its content -> Use this content to do a google search in a new tab.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "searchongoog",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [ "tabs",
    "https://*/*","http://*/*","activeTab"
  ],    
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*/*","http://*/*"],
      "js": ["background.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

With this I can get the information, but everytime I open a page it automatically gets it done. I dont want that, I want it to do the background.js only when the extension icon is clicked. I tried to invoke the background.js inside popup.html but it doesn't have access to the DOM to extract the information to search.

Any help would be great.

PS: I am a total noob on this, so dont flame me if I am doing totally wrong.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try "**programmatic injection**" instead of "match patterns injection".

Programmatic injection is useful especially when you don't want to inject code to every page which match the pattern, for example: code should be injected when user click the browser action button.

I wrote a simple example to demonstrate how to implement "programmatic inject":

First, you need to add a background page to register the "browser action" click event listener.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "searchongoog",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [ "tabs",
    "https://*/*","http://*/*","activeTab"
  ],
  "background":{
    "persistent":false,
    "page":"background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

Register the browser action click listener (injector.js is the script that you search the DOM and get content for new tab google searching).

Note: Please make sure that the browser action has no popup. This event will not fire if it has popup.

**background.html**

```
<script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"injector.js"});
});
</script>
```

**injector.js**

```
alert("Programmatic injection!");
```

**DEMO snapshot:**

[image]

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Why are you using manifest injected content scripts ? Also, please, don't encourage persistent background pages for no obvious reason.

Comment: @ExpertSystem thanks for your reminding. The manifest injected content script is author's requirement. I didn't modify it. And you're right! I should set persistent attribute to "false".

Comment: OP's requirement is to achieve what they want. I don't think they really care if the re is a manifest injected content script. Further more, since you are proposing a different approach (i.e. one that does work) it only makes sense to remove unnecessary parts of OP's (not working) approach. Just my two cents...

Comment: I cant make it work.
I don't understand, Do I need to write a html only with that code? Nothing else? I did that and suppose that in my injector.js I have "alert("test");" it won't fire up any alert.
My manifest it's the same as you proposed, still dont work

Comment: Sorry... it'a typo.... I updated the code of background.html and manifest file. You could try again.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am seeing the whole picture wrong but is the background.html just that code? Makes no sense, no <script> tags? Although if I put that inside a <script> tag I get an error about using inline code. 
Can you please display your whole background.html and injector.js.
This whole extension developing is really confuse for me. Thanks a lot for your help @Chickenrice